# Can someone explain this notation: $C_w([0,\infty),X)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, notation, banach-spaces, weak-convergence, weak-topology

I am studying a article that appear the notation
$$C_w([0,\infty); X)$$
and the explication is that it is the set of weakly-star continuous functions on $[ 0 , \infty)$
with values in $X$ ($X$ is a Banach space).
Can somebody explain it? Please. Whats a weakly-star continuous function on $[ 0 , \infty)$
with values in $X$?

Comment: Which parts give you trouble, and have you tried looking them up? Do you know what $[0,\infty)$ is? What continuous means in a simple case? What continuous means in general? What a Banach space is? What the weak-star topology is? If, say, you knew all of those except for the weak-star topology, have you tried searching for "weakly-star continuous"? Is there something in an explanation of it (or something else you searched for) giving you trouble?

Comment: @MarkS. I know what is $[0,\infty)$, continuity, Banach space, weak star topology. I tried search weakly star continuous. My question is, the topology weak star is defined I a DUAL SPACE, and $[0,\infty)$ is dual of somebody?

Comment: Weak star topology is not defined on $X$ unless $X$ is a dual space. So the definition has no meaning.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy what happen if replace $X$ for $X^*$?

Comment: Then you are talikng about all functions $f: [0,\infty) \to X^{*}$ such that inverse image of any weak* open set in $X^{*}$ is open in $[0,\infty)$. Why are you confused about this?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy this is what I wanted to hear, my question was if was required a weak star topology for $[0,\infty)$. Can I characterize these functions as $f(t_n)\to f(t)$, weak-star ever if $t_n \to t$? Thanks!

Comment: could you share the source of the article/paper/book?

Comment: @Nick Kozono 2016